# Capturing output from WScript.Shell in real time

Tags: windows, command-line, vbscript, hta, jscript

I'm using JScript (which is the same as VBScript pretty much) from within an .hta file, to open a new shell command and capture its output. Here's what I got so far after Googling a bit:

```
var shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell")
var e = shell.Exec("%comspec% /c ping google.com 2>&1 ") 
while(!e.StdOut.AtEndofStream) {
    var line = e.StdOut.ReadLine()
    document.getElementById('log').value = line
}
```

This works. However, it's not asynchronous. The while loop causes my .hta interface to just block (the UI becomes unusable) until the shell command finished. If I remove the `while loop`, the `shell.Exec` command doesn't seem to block, so the issue is somewhere within the loop.

I think the blocking issue only happens because I'm within an .hta environment. It doesn't seem to happen if I run my script through the command-line using `cscript.exe`

How can I avoid the blocking behavior and access the output of my command in real-time?

Comment: The loop still blocks in cscript.exe but since the console window is controlled by a helper process (conhost/csrss) you don't notice the blocking (This is OK and normal for a console application to do)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have to [fake a background thread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Threads#Using_setTimeout_to_schedule_tasks) by calling `setTimeOut` repeatedly and only doing a small amount of work in the timer callback...

Comment: Could you expand a little on that? Where would the `setTimeout` be needed? Isn't it asynchronous? So how would it matter?

Comment: Replace the while loop with code like I linked to. A while loop does not allow the HTA host application to process messages, setTimeout will...

Comment: The issue is actually deeper than what I thought. ReadLine() will block until there's something to read. This is why the interface stalls. Any ideas how I can get around this?

Comment: You can use Read(1) to read one character at the time, not sure if there is a non-blocking way to peek to see if there is anything to read...

Comment: Eheh nice idea, tried it, but also Read() blocks until there's something to read. From the methods here it seems like there's no other solution :( which sucks [TextStream Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/312a5kbt(v=vs.84).aspx)

Comment: My only suggestion is to embed a helper application (you need to write it) and extract it to %temp% at runtime, this helper application would act as a middle-man and report back a "nop" line every 200ms if there is no real output. I know this is not what you want so maybe you should ask a new question about doing a non-blocking peeking operation on a TextStream object on SO...

Answer (score 0):

As Anders pointed out, you need to implement pseudo multithread strategy, because
your GUI won't react to any user input, as long as JScript code (any function)
is executed.

I used setInterval() instead of setTimeout() for reasons given [here](http://javascript.about.com/library/blstvsi.htm).

This .hta

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Ping HTA (JScript)</title>
  <HTA:APPLICATION
    APPLICATIONNAME="PingHTA"
  >
  <SCRIPT Language="JScript" src="ping.js"></SCRIPT>
 </head>
 <body onload="onLoadBody()">
  <form name="anonymous">
   <h2>Ping HTA (JScript)</h2>
   <hr>
   <input id="bttStartPing" type="BUTTON" value="StartPing" onclick="startPing()">
   <hr>
   <textarea id="taDisplay" rows="25" cols="80"></textarea>
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

and .js

```
//= app globals
g_sCmd      = '%comspec% /c ping.exe /n 8 google.com 2>&1';
g_taDisplay = null;
g_PSIHandle = 0;
g_PSILock   = false;
g_oExec     = null;

//= prep for log
function onLoadBody() {
  g_taDisplay = window.document.getElementById("taDisplay");
  log("OnLoadBody() done.");
}

//= log
function log(msg) {
  g_taDisplay.value = new Date().toString() + "\n   " + msg + "\n" + g_taDisplay.value;
}

//= start job
function startPing() {
  if (0 == g_PSIHandle) {
     g_PSIHandle = setInterval(stepPing, 100);
     log('setInterval(stepPing, 100)');
     g_oExec = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell").Exec(g_sCmd);
     log("started " + g_sCmd);
  } else {
     log('***** Ping is running!');
  }
}

//= one step of job
function stepPing() {
  if (! g_PSILock) {
     g_PSILock = true;
     if (null !== g_oExec) {
        if (g_oExec.StdOut.AtEndofStream) {
           clearInterval(g_PSIHandle);
           g_PSIHandle = 0;
           log('StdOut.AtEndofStream, terminate ping');
           g_oExec.Terminate();
           g_oExec = null;
        } else {
           log(g_oExec.StdOut.ReadLine());
        }
     }
     g_PSILock = false;
  }
}
```

should demonstrate:

1. using .Exec in an .hta will open a shell window (for some people
   that is a disqualifier)
2. the .hta will start to pick up lines of ping output, before that
   process terminates
3. clicking the button while the process is running will intersperse
   the message with the ping output (although the reaction feels
   sluggish)

**A production version would have to spend much more effort on dealing
with the possible states of the .Exec and on error handling.**

For that, start your reseach [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2f38xsxe%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) and google for "WshScriptExec Object".

Comment: Great! This works. Is there a way to hide the command window that pops open? This may be a different question though.

Comment: @Luca - you can hide the console window (see (1) in my answer)

Comment: in your (1) answer you state that it will *open* a shell window. I want to avoid this.

Comment: Also, is there documentation as to what `new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell").Exec(g_sCmd)` returns? Like where did you find the `Terminate()` command, and other commands? I can't seem to find this information on the web

Comment: @LucaMatteis, the `Exec` method returns a [`WshScriptExec`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2f38xsxe%28VS.84%29.aspx) object.